# Xamarin.Forms and .NetStandard AppSettings

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I'm migrating a Class Library to .NetStandard 1.4. The class contains EF Models (I've already migrated that functionality)

The class library will be used by the following applications:

- A WPF app. There are no plans (for now) to migrate it to .NetStandard
- A Xamarin.Forms app
- Two Console (As services with TopShelf) apps. There are no plans (for now) to migrate it to .NetStandard

The Class Library uses some App.Config values like an API endpoint and some other useful information.

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseEndpoint"].ToString()
```

I've found an article that explains how to create an appsettings.json file and then use the values along the apps. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/warnov/2017/01/16/net-core-cmo-usar-app-settings-en-una-aplicacin-de-consola/  (I'm sorry, it is in Spanish )

Q:

- Will be posible to use this approach in the 3 different projects?
- Is there a better approach?